# jQuery - UI - Datepicker - Multi day selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI part of my CMS.

Specifically, the Datepicker pluggin to use Online calendar for selecting dates.

This pluggin has always worked well for me, and gives me no problems.

My drawback is when I need to select multiple days on the calendar, and that jQuery.datepicker can not do.

I have seen that there is a modification of it called "multiplesDatesPicker" (https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-D...-for-jQuery-UI)

I've linked to my CMS and I've started.

Works fine, I can select multiple dates, but:

- 1) Clicking on days, loaded into the text box selected dates, and this produces a constant flickering of the calendar.
- 2) days Selecting another month than the current (day of different months to October) the date written on the box, and reload the calendar month in which you were lost.

How can we solve RELOAD calendar to write in the text box?

You can see it here, e field is DATE

http://jsfiddle.net/cza76nrx/1/

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".datepiker").each(function () {
        jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults(jQuery.datepicker.regional['es']);
        var actualVal = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery(this).datepicker();
        jQuery(this).multiDatesPicker();
        jQuery(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
        jQuery(this).datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
        jQuery(this).val(actualVal);
    });
});
```

Flashes to update the contents of the box (the calendar will disappear, but as the focus is on the box reappears, losing month have progressed or regressed).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I  have enver used the `MultiplesDatesPicker` and going though the forums it seems the issue is related to parent Date Picker it uses.

And I found out the a bug reported for the same issue in [Git: Can we avoid the calendar from flickering / being redrawn after every selection?](https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/issues/67).

So, I came up with the solution stated in the Bug report, that is used for avoiding the orginal DatePicker being closed on select event.

```
$(this).multiDatesPicker({
    onSelect: function()          
      {
      $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;                               
      }
});
```

And i think it solves your both issue.

### Here is the [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cza76nrx/2/)

I hope this is what you have wanted.

Comment: The solution is OK, but not the correct and necessary.

Why?
Because when using this piece of code, calendar is ALWAYS open, and I do not want that. I want to be open to being in the field, but that focus to other field or press out of it need to close (as does the original datepicker).

Even if you delete or putting AUTOCLOSE to "true", if I select days, and pulse in another box or outside, it does not close. 

If I do not select anything and pulse anywhere if it is closed